# cannot invoke initializer for type SKproductsRequest with an argument type (productIdentifiers:Set<NSObject>)

Tags: ios, swift, nsset

Since Swift 2 im getting

> cannot invoke initializer for type SKproductsRequest with an argument
>   type (productIdentifiers:Set)

For in app purchase identifiers in my `NSSet`

[image]

```
if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {

        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects:
            "com.someurl.monthlyAutoRenewable",
            "com.someurl.annualAutoRenewable")

        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    else {


    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replacing

`let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)`

With

`let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)`

Fixes it